# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2+3k+2}{2} z^k = \frac{1}{(1-z)^3}$, without using differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, laurent-series

Show that,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2+3k+2}{2} z^k = \frac{1}{(1-z)^3}$$

where $ z \in \mathbb{C}, |z|< 1$

Well, I have figured out that is a Laurent series I have watched 3 videos in the topics but I still don't know how to prove it. I appreciate any kind of help a lot.

Comment: Hint:$$\frac{k^2+3k+2}2z^k=\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}2z^k=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}z^2}z^{k+2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My problem is that unfortunately I don't get the last step, can you help me with that? Do I have to take the second derivative also of $\frac{1}{1-z}{^{3}}$?

Comment: My hint indicates that the sum is given by$$\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}z^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k+2}=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}z^2}\frac{z^2}{1-z}$$using the geometric series formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI,

Based on Newton Binomial theorem known that:

$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{\alpha+1}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+\alpha}{k}z^k$

In our case $\alpha=2$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+2)!}{k!2!}z^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}z^k$

Answer (score 4):

hint...consider the sum of an infinite geometric series and differentiate it twice

Comment: can you give me a hint how to show it without differentiation? Thank you for the hint.

Comment: you could follow the steps outlined below or you could reverse-engineer the Binomial expansion of $(1-z)^{-3}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2+3k+2}{2} z^k$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac 12\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2z^k+\frac 32\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kz^k+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac 12A+\frac 32B+C$$

$$A=z+2^2z^2+3^2z^3+4^2z^4\cdots(a)$$
$$\Rightarrow zA=z^2+2^2z^3+3^2z^4+4^2z^5\cdots(b)$$
subtract $b$ from $a$,
$$(1-z)A=z+3z^2+5z^3+7z^4\cdots(c)$$
$$\Rightarrow z(1-z)A=z^2+3z^3+5z^4+7z^5\cdots(d)$$
subtract $d$ from $c$,
$$(1-z)^2A=z+2(z^2+z^3+z^3+\cdots)$$
$$\Rightarrow (1-z)^2A=z+2(\frac{z^2}{1-z})$$
$$\Rightarrow A=\frac{z+z^2}{(1-z)^3}$$
Similarly, you can find $B$ and $C$ and finally plug the values in our original expression to get the final result!

Answer (score 0):

You can verify in the infinite series $\sum_k\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}z^k(1-3z+3z^2-z^3)$ the constant term is $1$, and there are no overall $z$ and $z^2$ terms. For $n\ge3$, the $z^n$ coefficient is$$\begin{align}\tfrac{(n+1)(n+2)-3n(n+1)+3n(n-1)-(n-1)(n-2)}{2}&=\tfrac{(n+1)(2-2n)+(n-1)(2n+2)}{2}\\&=-(n+1)(n-1)+(n-1)(n+1)\\&=0.\end{align}$$The $|z|<1$ constraint results from $\sum_k\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}z^k$ having radius of convergence $1$.